# C11 _Generic() expression failing if being nested

Tags: c, c11

I'm trying to find out why nested `_Generic()` expressions are failing for me. If I don't nest them, they work fine.

Of course it's happening to me in a longer program, but I summarised it as a minimal working example that triggers exactly the same error as in the larger program.

I tried to check the code again and again, but found no smoking gun... what's the cause of the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct sta
    {
    char a;
    }ta;

typedef struct stb
    {
    short b;
    }tb;

typedef struct stc
    {
    int c;
    }tc;

#define MAGICNUMBER(X) _Generic((X), \
ta: 1, \
tb: 2, \
tc: 3 \
)

#define NESTEDMAGICNUMBER3(X) _Generic((X), \
ta: 1 \
)

#define NESTEDMAGICNUMBER2(X) _Generic((X), \
tb: 2, \
default: NESTEDMAGICNUMBER3(X) \
)

#define NESTEDMAGICNUMBER(X) _Generic((X), \
tc: 3, \
default: NESTEDMAGICNUMBER2(X) \
)

int     main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    ta a;
    tb b;
    tc c;
    
    printf("direct macro: ta has # %d\n",MAGICNUMBER(a));
    printf("direct macro: tb has # %d\n",MAGICNUMBER(b));
    printf("direct macro: tc has # %d\n",MAGICNUMBER(c));
    printf("nested macro: ta has # %d\n",NESTEDMAGICNUMBER(a)); /* Compile-time error why? */
    printf("nested macro: tb has # %d\n",NESTEDMAGICNUMBER(b)); /* Compile-time error why? */
    printf("nested macro: tc has # %d\n",NESTEDMAGICNUMBER(c)); /* Compile-time error why? */
    
    return 0;
    }
```

When compiling, I get this:

```
cc -o testgeneric testgeneric.c
testgeneric.c:49:39: error: controlling expression type 'tb' (aka 'struct stb') not compatible with any generic association type
        printf("nested macro: tb has # %d\n",NESTEDMAGICNUMBER(b)); /* Compile-time error why? */
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
testgeneric.c:36:10: note: expanded from macro 'NESTEDMAGICNUMBER'
default: NESTEDMAGICNUMBER2(X) \
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
testgeneric.c:31:10: note: expanded from macro 'NESTEDMAGICNUMBER2'
default: NESTEDMAGICNUMBER3(X) \
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
testgeneric.c:25:40: note: expanded from macro 'NESTEDMAGICNUMBER3'
#define NESTEDMAGICNUMBER3(X) _Generic((X), \
                                       ^~~
testgeneric.c:50:39: error: controlling expression type 'tc' (aka 'struct stc') not compatible with any generic association type
        printf("nested macro: tc has # %d\n",NESTEDMAGICNUMBER(c)); /* Compile-time error why? */
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
testgeneric.c:36:10: note: expanded from macro 'NESTEDMAGICNUMBER'
default: NESTEDMAGICNUMBER2(X) \
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
testgeneric.c:31:10: note: expanded from macro 'NESTEDMAGICNUMBER2'
default: NESTEDMAGICNUMBER3(X) \
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
testgeneric.c:25:40: note: expanded from macro 'NESTEDMAGICNUMBER3'
#define NESTEDMAGICNUMBER3(X) _Generic((X), \
                                       ^~~
2 errors generated.
```

Why does the nested version fail, while the non-nested version works fine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the nested version fail, while the non-nested version works fine?

Consider the expansion of `NESTEDMAGICNUMBER(b))`:

```
_Generic((b), tc: 3, default: _Generic((b), tb: 2, default: _Generic((b), ta: 1 ) ) )
```

The compiler is rejecting this expression because the subexpression `_Generic((b), ta: 1 )` is invalid on account of not having a case for the type of `b` (`tb`, a.k.a. `struct stb`).  The fact that that is not part of a generic alternative that will be selected is irrelevant -- every expression and subexpression in your program's source must be valid, regardless of whether it has any effect.  You could fix the problem by adding a `default` alternative to `NESTEDMAGICNUMBER3`:

```
#define NESTEDMAGICNUMBER3(X) _Generic((X), \
ta: 1, \
default: 0 \
)
```

Comment: That's it. I understand. I omitted the `default` in the last nested macro on purpose, so that the compiler triggers an error if the macro is used on an unexpected type. Would it be possible to trigger an error somehow if the last `default` entry is followed? It's a bit of a challenge: triggering a compiler error on a expression that at the same time looks correct to the compiler. Can that be done?

Comment: @cesss, you could consider adding specific generic alternatives to `NESTEDMAGICNUMBER3` that cover the whole overall set of types you want to accept, instead of using a `default` clause.  But of course, that seems to moot the purpose of the nested approach (and indeed, I would be inclined to avoid the nested approach, myself).  I don't think there's any other way to get compile time rejection of unwanted types, though you could achieve run time rejection via a special value of that final fallback alternative, maybe combined with an assertion.

Comment: @cesss You can write macros in the form `#define SOMETHING(X) _Generic((x), some_type : 1, default: 0)` then call them with `static_assert(SOMETHING(my_type), "my_type not supported");`. This also enables better compiler messages than "not compatible with any generic association type".

Answer (score 1):

In a `_Generic` expression, the passed-in type **must** match one of the given types or have a `default` part.

Let's take a look at the preprocessor output to see what's happening:

```
printf("direct macro: ta has # %d\n",_Generic((a), ta: 1, tb: 2, tc: 3 ));
printf("direct macro: tb has # %d\n",_Generic((b), ta: 1, tb: 2, tc: 3 ));
printf("direct macro: tc has # %d\n",_Generic((c), ta: 1, tb: 2, tc: 3 ));
printf("nested macro: ta has # %d\n",_Generic((a), tc: 3, default: _Generic((a), tb: 2, default: _Generic((a), ta: 1 ) ) ));
printf("nested macro: tb has # %d\n",_Generic((b), tc: 3, default: _Generic((b), tb: 2, default: _Generic((b), ta: 1 ) ) ));
printf("nested macro: tc has # %d\n",_Generic((c), tc: 3, default: _Generic((c), tb: 2, default: _Generic((c), ta: 1 ) ) ));
```

The first 3 lines use the non-nested macro.  In each of these cases, the passed-in type matches one of the 3 cases.

Now let's look at the nested case, specifically the second one:

```
_Generic((b), tc: 3, default: _Generic((b), tb: 2, default: _Generic((b), ta: 1 ) ) ))
```

In the last case: `_Generic((b), ta: 1 )`, the type of `b` is not `ta` and there is no `default` case, so this is where the compiler complains.  Note here that **all** `_Generic` expressions must be valid, even if they aren't ultimately the case that gets evaluated.

You can fix this by giving the innermost macro a `default` case:

```
#define NESTEDMAGICNUMBER3(X) _Generic((X), \
ta: 1, \
default: 0 \
)
```

Comment: It's a pity that two correct answers cannot be accepted. I checked on @John Bollinger answer because he submitted it first, but your answer would be as elegible as his.